# Trying to hide all bbcode-generated divs within a span, but it isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's an example of the html:

```
<!-- Working Example-->
<span class='prv' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand';>
    This text is shown...
</span>
<span class='cnt' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand';>
    This text will be hidden on load and shown when the 'prv' class is clicked.
</span>
<!-- Broken Example-->
<span class='prv' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand';>
    This text is shown...</span>
<span class='cnt' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand';>
    <div class="bbcode_center" style="text-align:center">
        This text isn't hidden even though I want it to be.
    </div>
</span>
```

In the working example, there aren't any bbcode tags, so no bbcode class divs are generated - but I can't just get rid of the bbcode tags because I need them displayed.

Here the jquery code:

```
function run_on_load() {
    $('.cnt').hide();
    //$('.cnt').children().hide(); <- Tried this too
}
$('.prv').click(function() {
    $('.prv').hide();
    $('.cnt').show();
});
$('.cnt').click(function() {
    $('.cnt').hide();
    $('.prv').show();
});
```

This all works for the first example, but hides nothing in the second example. How do I make it so that the jquery code hides everything within the 'cnt' class span indiscriminately?

Also, the span in the broken example isn't clickable, apparently for the same reason. Is there a way to make all divs within the span clickable, like having a jquery findall type function add the clickable style to each individual bbcode class div?

**Edit:** To be clear, what happens in the working example is exactly what I want: 'prv' (the preview text) is shown, and when it is clicked it hides itself and instead shows 'cnt' (the full content/text). The only issue with the broken example is that nothing within bbcode divs in 'cnt' is ever hidden when I want it all hidden indiscriminately.

Comment: Do you want all broken and working code to your project ?

Comment: @MujthabaIbrahim I want all the text inside the span to be hidden. Right now any text that is on the 'top level' of span is hidden, but not the text that is within generated bbcode class divs within the span. I want everything within the span hidden, including text within divs within the span

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to wrap the `.hide()` inside a `$(document).ready(function() {})`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cnt').hide();
});

$('.prv').click(function() {
  $('.prv').hide();
  $('.cnt').show();
});

$('.cnt').click(function() {
  $('.cnt').hide();
  $('.prv').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='prv' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand'>
    This text is shown...
</span>
<span class='cnt' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand'>
    <div class="bbcode_center" style="text-align:center">
        This text isn't hidden even though I want it to be.
    </div>
</span>
```

This way, clicking on the preview hides the preview and shows the full content, and clicking on the full content hides it and shows the preview.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, but this part isn't actually wrong. The point of the function is to toggle which is shown, 'prv' (a preview), or 'cnt' (the full content), so this part works fine

Comment: Ahh, slight confusion there. I've updated my answer to correct this.

Comment: Using document ready works exactly the same, as 'run_on_load()' is already running when the page loads without a hitch. The only problem is when divs are introduced within the 'cnt' span

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.cnt').hide();
});
```

instead Old code:

```
function run_on_load() {

    //$('.cnt').children().hide(); <- Tried this too
}
```

You have declare run_on_load() but not called on document load  . above i code is jquery short hand to do that

Comment: Thanks, but it is exactly the same as before. The text in the span that isn't within divs is hidden, but the bbcode class divs are not.

Comment: have you see that fiddle i have posted ?

Comment: what i have achieved is hiding all spans which have class .cnt on load and on .pvr click and hiding .pvr class spans on .cnt click . is its your requirement

Comment: It doesn't hide the divs within the spans though, which was my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit helped me solve it. Turns out I just needed to change the spans to divs -- the html wasn't validating properly because you can't put divs inside spans, apparently.